# string VS union of two literal types accepted

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code compiles?

```
type EntityType = "x" | "y"

type myFunc = (id: number, categoryType: EntityType) => void

const x: myFunc = (id: number, categoryType: string) => {
    // some code here
}
```

How can I make myFunc accept only "x" or "y"?

**EDIT:**

From the above, tt looks like we can do x: typeX = y: typeY where typeY is a superset of typeX.

Why does the compiler screams the following

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EntityType'

```
type EntityType = "x" | "y"

const someString: string = "x"

const x: EntityType = someString
```

The above error is exactly the type of error I was hoping to receive for the first snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can safely assign a function that can handle much wider range of values to a function that can handle only a limited subset of those values.
As `x` can accept only `x | y` values in `categoryTypes` argument, the RHS (right hand side) function can safely deal with them.

```typescript
type EntityType = "x" | "y"

type myFunc = (id: number, categoryType: EntityType) => void

const x: myFunc = (id: number, categoryType: string) => {
    // some code here
}

x(1, 'x')
x(2, 'y')
x(3, 'a') // error
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpl3bm)

---

Answer to updated question:

> From the above, tt looks like we can do x: typeX = y: typeY where typeY is a superset of typeX.

In short: no, you can not.

Assignment works only in the way when RHS type is a *subtype* of LHS type. For functions it's absolutely the same. But functions are defined by **two** types. And functions are *contravariant* in their arument type while they are *covariant* in their return type.  That happens due to [variance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance). So for functions subtyping works this way:

```
type Fn1 = (arg1: Arg1) => Ret1
type Fn2 = (arg2: Arg2) => Ret2
Fn1 extends Fn2 // means you can assign: const fn2: Fn2 = fn1 as Fn1
  <=> // then and only then
(arg1: Arg1) => Ret1 extends (arg2: Arg2) => Ret2
  <=>
Ret1 extends Ret2 'and' Arg2 extends Arg1
```

As you may notice argument's type relation goes in the opposite direction. That still doesn't allow those types to be assignable in the same sense as a plain values assignment. The opposite (*contra*) direction works only when they're encountered in argument's position.